# Certificate chain length not valid

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

We have an weird situation. While set upping a connection our application perform a bunch of security checks. One of these is to check if the chain length is correct. We know that it should be 3: Root, intermediate and server.

When we are connecting to a server using Android application we get as a response only two certificates intermediate and server - no root. But when we perform checking thought web browser we came up with a research on Android 5.0 we see 3 and on Android 4.3 we see two of them. Connection form iOS results in 3 certificates.

Is it a server or Android? What we can do to get also root certificate?

EDIT:
We download certificates (root and intermediate) from the browser and create a keystore from them and put it in the app assets. Then in our CustomTrustManager we are comparing certificates from the keystore with the certificates which came from the server we connect.

Basically our comparison is based on certificates fingerprint. The problem is that the root certificate is not coming from the server and there is no ability to compare it.

But we came out with the idea.

We can compare that intermediate ceritifcate which came from server is signed by the root certificate which is harcoded in the app.

I think this is sufficently secure.

And the we will compare only intermediate fingerprints.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea of how you do the checks exactly, but in general:

- The server must sent the servers certificate and all intermediate certificates leading from the server certificate to the built-in root CA. If chain certificates are missing some browsers (like Chrome on Desktop) attempt to fill in the missing certificates while other (like most applications which are not browsers) fail validation because the trust chain could not be created.
- The server should not sent the root CA itself but some servers do anyway. In this case the root CA sent by the server will be ignored.
- Depending on the root-CA stored in the browser/system there might be different trust path which also usually have a different length. This is especially true when cross-signing is involved which is usually the case when introducing a new root-CA. Since these are initially not in the browser/system CA store they get signed by another CA which is in the trust store but later the new root-CA is in the trust store so the chain is shorter. This process is also used currently to replace various root-CA which used 1024-bit RSA with root-CA using more strong keys (i.e. 4096 bit).

This means the chain length you see depends on a lot of factors:

- How you look: do you look at the chain sent by the server or the chain constructed by the system? The latter will contain the root-CA while the first should not but might.
- Which root-CA's exist on the system: older systems might construct longer chains because the newer root-CA or not yet in the system.

Comment: We download certificates (root and intermediate) from the browser and create a keystore from them and put it in the app assets.

Then in our CustomTrustManager we are comparing certificates from the keystore with the certificates which came from the server

we connect.

 

Basically our comparison is based on certificates fingerprint.

The problem is that the root certificate is not coming from the server and there is no ability to compare it.

Comment: @elon: it is not clear why you do anything like this at all. The established way to check that you are connected to the expected server is to verify the servers certificate or its public key, i.e. [certificate or public key pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning). If the servers certificate gets compromised an attacker can also include all the chain certificates since they are public, so it makes no use to compare these too.